# Can private browsing prevent CSRF vulnerability?

Tags: csrf

While I know there are standard ways to prevent CSRF attacks like use of CSRF tokens etc, I want to know if the CSRF vulnerability can be prevented using private browsing (incognito mode browser). As I understand private browsing would prevent accessing my site specific cookies by other sites and thus it should prevent CSRF vulnerability?

Comment: If you browse your webmail in incognito and receive a malicious email that tricks you into making a request, that request will be made in incognito as well, and therefore has access to your incognito cookies.

Comment: Looks like scripting from other sites cannot do CSRF attacks in private mode but Emails can do.